# Backup and restore the Managed properties(Metadata properties) of the search service application in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: search, managed-metadata, crawling, managed-property

We are going to reset the Search Index in our SharePoint 2010 environment, I guess this will remove all the Managed properties(Metadata properties) from the search service application. So, would like to backup the Managed property settings and restore after contents are re-crawled.

Please let me know if there is a powershell script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}


function ResetIndex {
    param ($searchapp)

    #Reset index with the following options in brackets:
    #Disable Alerts $true/$false
    #Ignore unreachable server $true/$false
    try
    {
        Write-Host "Attempting to reset the index...please wait"
        $searchapp.Reset($false, $false)
        Write-Host "Index successfully reset" -ForegroundColor Blue
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "There was a problem resetting the index:" $_ -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}


function BackupMetadataProperties {
    param ($searchapp, $MetadataPropertyLogs)

    "PID;Name;Description;Type;HasMultiValue;IncludeAll;EnabledForScoping;IsSortable;PutInPropertyBlob;MappingCount;CrawledProperty;Category;VariantType" | out-file $MetadataPropertyLogs;

    Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp |% {
    $prop= $_;
    $propData = $prop.Pid.ToString() + ";" + $prop.Name.ToString() + ";" + $prop.Description.ToString() + ";" + $prop.ManagedType.ToString() + ";" + $prop.HasMultipleValues.ToString() + ";" + $prop.RespectPriority + ";" + $prop.EnabledForScoping.ToString() + ";" + $prop.MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex.ToString() + ";" + $prop.PutInPropertyBlob.ToString() + ";" + $prop.GetMappings().Count.ToString(); 

        $prop.GetMappedCrawledProperties($prop.GetMappings().Count) |% {
        $propMapping = $propData  + ";" + $_.Name.ToString() + ";" + $_.CategoryName.ToString() + ";" + $_.VariantType.ToString();
        $propMapping | out-file $MetadataPropertyLogs -append;
        }
    }
}


function StartFullCrawl {
    param ( $SearchApp, $ContentSource)

    $CrawlContentSource = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $SearchApp  -Identity $ContentSource;
        if ($CrawlContentSource.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle")
        {
            Write-Host "Stopping currently running crawl for content source $($CrawlContentSource.Name)...";
            $CrawlContentSource.StopCrawl();

            do { Start-Sleep -Seconds 60 }
            while ($CrawlContentSource.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle");
        }

        Write-Host "Starting full crawl for content source $($CrawlContentSource.Name)...";
        $CrawlContentSource.StartFullCrawl();
}

function checkCrawlStatus {
    param ($searchapp)
    $CrawlContentSource = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $SearchApp  -Identity $ContentSource;
    if ($CrawlContentSource.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle")
        {   
        do { Start-Sleep -Seconds 300 }
            while ($CrawlContentSource.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle");
    }
}


function CreateMetadataProperty {
    param ( $searchapp, $MetadataPropertyName, $Description, $Type, $HasMultiValue, $IncludeAll, $EnabledForScoping, $IsSortable, $PutInPropertyBlob, $CrawledProperty, $Category, $VariantType)

    $category = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory  -SearchApplication $searchapp –Identity $Category ;
    $crawledproperty = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Category $category -VariantType $VariantType -Name $CrawledProperty;

    If (!($crawledproperty -eq $null))
    {
        $managedproperty = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp  -Identity $MetadataPropertyName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        if( ($managedproperty -eq $null))
        {
            $managedproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Name $MetadataPropertyName -Type $Type -Description $Description -EnabledForScoping $EnabledForScoping -RespectPriority $IncludeAll -Confirm:$false;
            If (!($IsSortable -eq 0))
            {  
                $managedproperty.MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex = $IsSortable;
                $managedproperty.Update();
            }

            If ($HasMultiValue -eq $True)
            {  
                $managedproperty.HasMultipleValues = $true;
                $managedproperty.Update();
            }

            If ($PutInPropertyBlob -eq $True)
            {  
                $managedproperty.PutInPropertyBlob = $true;
                $managedproperty.Update();
            }
        }
        New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -SearchApplication $searchapp -ManagedProperty $managedproperty -CrawledProperty $crawledproperty
    }
    else
    {
        write-host -f Red "Crawl property is missing, you might need to recrawl your content source to get it."
        "Crawl property $CrawledProperty is missing, you might need to recrawl your content source to get it." | out-file $ErrorLog -append;    
    }

    if (!$?)
    {
        "An error has occurred" | out-file $ErrorLog -append;   
    }
}


function Main {

BackupMetadataProperties $searchapp $MetadataPropertyLogs;
ResetIndex $searchapp;

$contentSource = @("Local SharePoint sites","People Content Search","Site Registry","Social Data");

$contentSource |% {
    StartFullCrawl $searchapp $_.ToString();
}

$contentSource |% {
    checkCrawlStatus $searchapp $_.ToString();
}

$dictionary = @{}
$dictionary.Add("Text",1); 
$dictionary.Add("Integer",2);
$dictionary.Add("Decimal",3);
$dictionary.Add("DateTime",4);
$dictionary.Add("YesNo",5);

$MetadataProperties = GC $MetadataPropertyLogs;
$MetadataProperties |% {
    [Array]$MetadataProperty = $_.ToString() -split ";"
    $MetadataPropertyName = $MetadataProperty[1];
    $Description =  $MetadataProperty[2];
    $Type = $dictionary[$MetadataProperty[3]];
    $HasMultiValue = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($MetadataProperty[4]); 
    $IncludeAll = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($MetadataProperty[5]);
    $EnabledForScoping = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($MetadataProperty[6]);
    $IsSortable = $MetadataProperty[7];
    $PutInPropertyBlob = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($MetadataProperty[8]);
    $CrawledProperty = $MetadataProperty[10];
    $Category = $MetadataProperty[11];
    $VariantType = $MetadataProperty[12];

    CreateMetadataProperty $searchapp  $MetadataPropertyName $Description $Type $HasMultiValue $IncludeAll $EnabledForScoping $IsSortable $PutInPropertyBlob $CrawledProperty $Category $VariantType; 
}
}

$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication;
$MetadataPropertyLogs = "D:\Scripts\searchReIndex\propData_Sample.txt";
$ErrorLog = "D:\Scripts\searchReIndex\Error.txt";

Main;
```